# Class service with the annotation @Transactional does not update the data in the database

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot, eclipselink

I have a class (short code)   (more code https://pastebin.com/m3wUwyHx)

```
@Service("contributionPersistenceService")
@Transactional(rollbackFor = {...})
public class ContributionPersistenceServiceImpl implements ContributionPersistenceService {
...
@Override
public void createOtherTitleContribution(
        ContributionNew<OtherTitle> contribution,
        Long movieId,
        Long userId
) {
    final List<MovieOtherTitle> otherTitlesEntities = movie.getOtherTitles().stream()
            .filter(otherTitle -> otherTitle.getStatus() == EditStatus.ACCEPTED).collect(Collectors.toList());

   contribution.getIdsToDelete()
            .forEach(id ->
                    this.setReportedForDelete(otherTitlesEntities, id)
            );
}
...
public void setReportedForDelete(final List<? extends MovieInfo> enties, final Long id) {
    enties.forEach(entity -> {
        if(entity.getId() == id) {
            entity.setReportedForDelete(true);
        }
    });
}
}
```

The problem is that when I want to change the value `reportedForDelete` for an entity, it is not saved to the database.

Only such commands come out.

```
    [EL Fine]: sql: 2017-12-02 22:00:39.016--ClientSession(2007386597)--Connection(1901834254)--SELECT ID, activation_token, EMAIL, email_change_token, ENABLED, modified_date, new_email, PASSWORD, registration_date, USERNAME, UUID FROM users WHERE ((ID = ?) AND (ENABLED = ?))
    bind => [2 parameters bound]
[EL Fine]: sql: 2017-12-02 22:00:39.024--ClientSession(2007386597)--Connection(1901834254)--SELECT ID, BUDGET, RATING, STATUS, TITLE, TYPE FROM movies WHERE ((ID = ?) AND (STATUS = ?))
    bind => [2 parameters bound]
[EL Fine]: sql: 2017-12-02 22:00:39.03--ClientSession(2007386597)--Connection(1901834254)--SELECT ID, dtype, REPORTEDFORDELETE, REPORTEDFORUPDATE, STATUS, MOVIE_ID, USER_ID, other_title_country, other_title FROM movies_info WHERE ((MOVIE_ID = ?) AND (dtype = ?)) ORDER BY ID ASC
    bind => [2 parameters bound]
[EL Fine]: sql: 2017-12-02 22:00:39.079--ClientSession(2007386597)--Connection(1901834254)--UPDATE SEQUENCE SET SEQ_COUNT = SEQ_COUNT + ? WHERE SEQ_NAME = ?
    bind => [2 parameters bound]
[EL Fine]: sql: 2017-12-02 22:00:39.082--ClientSession(2007386597)--Connection(1901834254)--SELECT SEQ_COUNT FROM SEQUENCE WHERE SEQ_NAME = ?
    bind => [1 parameter bound]
[EL Fine]: sql: 2017-12-02 22:00:39.21--ClientSession(2007386597)--Connection(1901834254)--INSERT INTO contributions (ID, creation_date, FIELD, STATUS, user_comment, verification_comment, verification_date, MOVIE_ID, USER_ID, verification_user) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
    bind => [10 parameters bound]
[EL Fine]: sql: 2017-12-02 22:00:39.217--ClientSession(2007386597)--Connection(1901834254)--INSERT INTO contributions_ids_to_delete (contribution_id, element_id_to_delete) VALUES (?, ?)
    bind => [2 parameters bound]
[EL Fine]: sql: 2017-12-02 22:00:39.219--ClientSession(2007386597)--Connection(1901834254)--INSERT INTO contributions_sources (contribution_id, SOURCES) VALUES (?, ?)
    bind => [2 parameters bound]
```

There is no UPDATE command for the MovieInfo entity table.

The annotation `@Transactional` works in such a way that whatever you edit in the entity is automatically updated in the database, and here it does not work.

I tried to save the object immediately after editing, but it also does not change the field in the database.

```
if(entity.getId() == id) {
            entity.setReportedForDelete(true);
            this.entityManager.persist(entity);
        }
```

Comment: I think you're looping over an unattached collection after you execute the collect method.  Try to loop directly over the collection `movie.getOtherTitles()`, furthermore, can you tell me if `movie.getOtherTitles()` is a one-to-many mapping or something mapped?

Comment: Where are you actually attempting to save/persist?

Comment: Does entity.getId==id? You haven’t shown anything that indicates it would.